# python: force two zeroes after dot when converting float to string

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I am currently trying to force python to keep two zeroes after converting a float to a string, i.e.:

150.00 instead of 150.0

I am not very experienced with python and thus can only think of a brute force method to achieve this. Is there a built in functionality to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> "%.02f" % 150
'150.00'
```

Edit: Just tested, does work in 3.2 actually. It also works in older versions of Python, whilst the format methods do not - however, upgrading and using the format methods is preferred where possible. If you can't upgrade, use this.

Comment: This will also work in Python 3.x.  It's not even deprecated, though the new format syntax is recommended.

Comment: Yeah, just tested 3.2 as I wasn't sure. I prefer this over the new format for numbers myself, as it just seems a lot cleaner. Although I suppose it's a habit I should drop.... Also, this method works on older versions of python, whilst the format does not - something which is useful on systems where you're stuck on Python2.4, for example

Comment: As long as it's not deprecated and it fits your needs, I don't see too much of a reason to give up using the old syntax.

Comment: thanks, I think I am running on a pretty old version of python and this works!

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> "{0:.2f}".format(150)
'150.00'
```

or

```
>>> format(150, ".2f")
'150.00'
```

For an introduction to string formatting, see [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) and the links given there.

Comment: hmm i get the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'" do I need to import something special? thanks!

Comment: You seem to be using some rather old version of Python.  This syntax was introduced in Python 2.6.

Comment: If you're on older versions of Python, there is no format method - such as 2.4. If you can't upgrade your python version, then the method I posted will work, although upgrading and using this is preferred.

Comment: ah got it allready thanks, I think I am running on a version of python not supporting format.

Comment: Don't forget field numbers for Python 2.6 compatibility ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446964/valueerror-zero-length-field-name-in-format-error-in-python-3-0-3-1-3-2