# ValueError: zero length field name in format python

Tags: python, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“ValueError: zero length field name in format” error in Python 3.0,3.1,3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446964/valueerror-zero-length-field-name-in-format-error-in-python-3-0-3-1-3-2)

I have spent hours trying to solve this problem but to no avail. I read [this guide](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/string.html).
I haven't found any examples how to do what I need.

When I run the script I get this error (partly omitted):

```
Traceback (...):
   [...]
   output.write("{: > 026,.18e} {: > 026,.18e}\n".format(x,y))
ValueError: zero length field name in format.
```

The code is written in python 2.6 or 2.7 but I run python 3.1. How would I need to change output format so that it would work?

```
def f(x,y,a = 0.01):
    return y/(a+x)-y**3

def ekspEuler(N,dat):
    output = open(dat,"w")
    h = 3.0/N
    x,y = 0,1 #zac.pogoj

    for i in range(1,N+2):
        output.write("{: > 026,.18e} {: > 026,.18e}\n".format(x,y))
        y += h*f(x,y)
        x = i*h
    output.close()
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, what do you want to *do*? Or asked differently, why don't you want `"{}{}".format(x,y)`?

Comment: Is the problem that there are two specifiers in one bracket? I omitted .18e and then I get OverflowError:(34, 'Numerical result our of range')

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Chances are that you're running an old Python version, and not 3.1. In Python 2.6, you need indices in the format specs, like this:

```
"{0} {1}\n".format(x,y)
```

Update your Python version to a recent one, preferably 2.7 or 3.2, to fix the problem. According to the documentation, leaving out the numeric indices [should work in Python 3.1](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> Changed in version 3.1: The positional argument specifiers can be omitted, so '{} {}' is equivalent to '{0} {1}'.

Comment: I'm running python 3.1.3 and I'm using Geanny. I don't know how to install 3.2 version. I'm new to linux.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what *Geanny* is. Do you mean the editor [Geany](http://www.geany.org/)? In any case, you can find out your Python version with `import sys;print(sys.version)`. There are many Linux distributions, which one are you using?

Comment: It's Geany. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. You were right. I'm using 2.6.5. I tried with this:                                          output.write("{0: > 026,.18e} {1: > 026,.18e}\n".format(x,y))    And I get ValueError:Invalid conversion specification

Comment: In the current [Ubuntu 11.10, Python 2.7 is the default](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/python). So you can just update your Ubuntu installation - I wouldn't recommend an old one to a beginner anyways. Alternatively, [install a newer Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233536/python-2-7-on-ubuntu) on your system, or make your program run under Python3 by starting it with `#!/usr/bin/env python3.1`.

Comment: I had 11.10 but I didn't like it. I will move to linux mint next.  Now it runs 3.1.2 and that error doesn't show up anymore. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This applies to python 6.6 in centos 6,x