# ValueError: zero length field name in format in Python2.6.6

Tags: python, format

I use this python shell to generate a string:

```
>>>':'.join("{:x}\n".format(random.randint(0, 2**16 - 1)) for i in range(4))
```

When I run this shell in Python2.7.5, everything goes okay. But it occurs `ValueError: zero length field name in format` when Python version is `2.6.6`. What should I run this shell fine when Python version is `2.6.6`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054122/valueerror-zero-length-field-name-in-format-python

Answer (score 80, accepted):

In Python versions 2.6 or earlier, you need to explicitly number the format fields:

```
':'.join("{0:x}\n".format(random.randint(0, 2**16 - 1)) for i in range(4))
#          ^
```

You can read about this in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> Changed in version 2.7: The positional argument specifiers can be omitted, so `'{} {}'` is equivalent to `'{0} {1}'`.

Comment: This applies to centos 6.x