# String format() gives syntaxx error

Tags: python, formatting

I have this simple python 3.x code:

```
str = "{} ({}) is already aliased to {} ({})".format(nodeName, node['ipAddress']), n2['dnsName'], n2['ipAddress'])
```

All 4 arguments to format() are string, but I get this error:

```
str = "{} ({}) is already aliased to {} ({})".format(nodeName, node['ipAddress'], n2['dnsName'], n2['ipAddress'])
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

If I print node['ipAddress'] and node['dnsName'] manually using just print(), I see this:

```
dnsName = yuckyre.foobar.com

ipAddress = 192.168.1.10
<type 'str'>
```

Not sure why " appears". Maybe that's a clue to the problem?

Comment: `nodeName, node['ipAddress']),` <-- extra bracket

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code to remove the bracket. Still get an error (ValueError: zero length field name in format)

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446964/valueerror-zero-length-field-name-in-format-error-in-python-3-0-3-1-3-2

Comment: Yeah... that's the problem. It's 2.6.6