# parsing URL to generate delimited file

Tags: python, parsing

I want to parse a URL,partial output of which comes as below html lines by using basic urllib2 and .read()

```
<hr>
<h2>Cluster Summary (Heap Size is 555 MB/26.6 GB)</h2>
< table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
< tr><th>Running Map Tasks</th><th>Running Reduce Tasks</th><th>Total Submissions</th><th>Nodes</th><th>Occupied Map Slots</th><th>Occupied Reduce Slots</th><th>Reserved Map Slots</th><th>Reserved Reduce Slots</th><th>Map Task Capacity</th><th>Reduce Task Capacity</th><th>Avg. Tasks/Node</th><th>Blacklisted Nodes</th><th>Excluded Nodes</th><th>MapTask Prefetch Capacity</th></tr>
< tr><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>5576</td><td><a href="machines.jsp?type=active">8</a></td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>352</td><td>128</td><td>60.00</td><td><a href="machines.jsp?type=blacklisted">0</a></td><td><a href="machines.jsp?type=excluded">0</a></td><td>0</td></tr></table>
< br>
< hr>
```

Now to get meaningful information from above HTML I trying to use HTMLParser ( other options showed after research like Beautifulsoup,lxml,pyquery not available in my environment and i dont have sudo to install it)

Expected output is a file with some delimiter, say comma

```
Running Map Tasks,31
Running Reduce Tasks,0
Total Submissions,5587
Nodes,8
Occupied Map Slots,31
Occupied Reduce Slots,0 
Reserved Map Slots,0 
Reserved Reduce Slots,0 
Map Task Capacity,352 
Reduce Task Capacity,128 
Avg. Tasks/Node,60.00 
Blacklisted Nodes,0 
Excluded Nodes,0 
MapTask Prefetch Capacity ,0
```

Please check

***********updates********
If i go for other options like beautifulsoup, will it allow to limit search for particular block e.g. Cluster Summary, as my html will have different sections

Comment: No need for sudo to install things locally.

Comment: ok, but not able to write to lib directory while installing

Comment: So use a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to/want to do this "by hand", you can resort to string manipulation and/or regular expressions. Assuming that you found the relevant lines by iterating over the HTML:

```
import re

line1 = "< tr><th>Running Map Tasks</th><th>Running Reduce Tasks</           th><th>Total Submissions</th><th>Nodes</th><th>Occupied Map Slots</          th><th>Occupied Reduce Slots</th><th>Reserved Map Slots</th><th>Reserved     Reduce Slots</th><th>Map Task Capacity</th><th>Reduce Task Capacity</        th><th>Avg. Tasks/Node</th><th>Blacklisted Nodes</th><th>Excluded Nodes</    th><th>MapTask Prefetch Capacity</th></tr>"

line2 = '< tr><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>5576</td><td><a href="machines.jsp?    type=active">8</a></td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>352</     td><td>128</td><td>60.00</td><td><a href="machines.jsp?type=blacklisted">0</ a></td><td><a href="machines.jsp?type=excluded">0</a></td><td>0</td></tr></  table>'


headers= (line1.replace('< tr>', '').
  replace("</tr>", "").
  replace("<th>", "").
  split("</th>"))

matches = re.findall("<td>(.+?)</td>", line2)
clean_matches = []
for m in matches:
    if m.startswith('<'):
        clean_matches.append(re.search('>(.+?)<', m).group(1))
    else:
        clean_matches.append(m)

for h, m in zip(headers, clean_matches):
    print("{}: {}".format(h, m))
```

For the first line, I'm using [.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) and [.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get rid of the tags and split at the right places. For the "data" line, I'm using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get the `<td>`'s content. If the content starts with a tag, the regex searches for the first text node in the `<td>`. As always, this code is quite brittle and can easily break, if the server formats the output only a little different.

If you are getting `zero length field name` errors, you are using an old Python version. Assuming that you can't change this, you have to change the `print` function/statement to either use `{0}: {1}` or `print "%s: %s" % (h, m)`.

See also [the python documentation on string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Comment: Thanks Jasper    print("{}: {}".format(h, m))
ValueError: zero length field name in format
 working on this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446964/valueerror-zero-length-field-name-in-format-error-in-python-3-0-3-1-3-2 you seem zo be using python <2.7. I'll update the answer.